# Angular JS scope leak with element.empty()

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

In an Angular.JS project I have a directive with a complex template, instantiated thousands of times (in a grid).

For performance reasons, I had to split the template in multiple sub templates. Depending on directive's scope values combinations, I choose a sub template.

The performance gain is real (> 100 on very big grids), but in some cases (when the sub template contains a ng-repeat directive) Angular is calling functions declared in scope of deleted DOM elements.

I reduced the problem to the following minimal code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myDirective', ['$compile', '$log', function ($compile, $log) {
  function display(scopeId, x) {
    $log.log('func called with', x, 'in scope', scopeId);

    return x;
  }

  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.array = [1, 2, 3];
      scope.display = display;

      scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.abc;
      }, function (newValue) {
        var newContent = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="item in array">{{display($id, item)}}</div>');

        element.empty();

        element.append($compile(newContent)(scope))
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/yss4yskm/6/

Each time the element is replaced (when you click on checkbox), each scope created by ng-repeat is leaked: the scope continue to log to the browser console, Batarang shows the leaked scopes too.

Should not `element.empty()` delete all the children scopes?

Why the problem only occurs with the ng-repeat directive?

I can avoid the leak by creating a child scope and destroying when needed (https://jsfiddle.net/yss4yskm/9/) but I shouldn't have to.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myDirective', ['$compile', '$log', function ($compile, $log) {
  var childScope;

  function display(scopeId, x) {
    $log.log('func called with', x, 'in scope', scopeId);

    return x;
  }

  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.array = [1, 2, 3];
      scope.display = display;

      scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.abc;
      }, function (newValue) {
        element.empty();

        if (childScope) {
            childScope.$destroy();
        }

        element.append(angular.element('<div ng-repeat="item in array">{{display($id, item)}}</div>'));

        childScope = scope.$new();

        $compile(element.contents())(childScope);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should do `element.remove()` which will remove scope too..

Comment: `element.remove()` does not remove the scope. The scope needs to be explicitly destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to myself.

Looking at Angular sources. `element.empty()` call jQuery.empty() and nothing more!

When the DOM element is deleted, the reference to the angular scope is remove but the scope is still in the linked list of the child scopes of its parent.

The child scope is therefore required.

Comment: `empty()` does not remove an element ... it removes it's inner html

Comment: So having the `childScope` is the only solution to this?